# Django queryset to json

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to unpack my query set to json?

For example:

```
test.objects.all()

return self.create_response(request, {
   'objects': test,


 })
```

ie something like `test.tojson()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.core import serializers
serializers.serialize('json', qs)
```

Its not a hundred percent error proof but it's sufficient for most use cases

Answer (score 2):

[Serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

```
from django.core import serializers
test = serializers.serialize("json", test.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

And since Django 3.2 version there is a new database function [JSONObject](https://And%20since%20Django%203.2%20version%20there%20is%20a%20new%20database%20function):

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import JSONObject


queryset = queryset.annotate(_json=JSONObject(**{key: F(key) for key in fields}))
data = list(queryset.values_list("_json", flat=True))
```